# DynamicResource doesn't show the correct value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary

I have a problem with DynamicResource and MergedDictionary.
I have a software which can be displayed in different languages (English, Spanish, German) and I have a lot of ResourceDictionaries.
I give you one example of a dictionary, which is called "Documentation.xaml":

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <system:String x:Key="ProductNumber">Product Number</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="Notes">Notes</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="Logo">Logo</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="InspectionTask">Inspection task</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="ProductDescription">Product Description</system:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This my "default" ResourceDictionary.
I have two other Dictionaries that are called "Documentation.de-DE.xaml" and Documentation-es-ES.xaml" for german and english.
They are nearly the same as the default Dictionary. The only difference is the displayed string.

Now to my problem:
When I access the ressource via "DynamicResource" I get the result from the active Dictionary. (Example: I get "Descripcion de producto" for the "ProductDescription" in Spanish.) If the Entry is available inside the Dictionary everything works fine. 
The problem appears when one entry is not available.
Assuming following situation:
I am running the software in spanish and want to change it to german, but one entry in the dictionary is not available, then the software is not using the default entry for it. I still has the value from the spanish dictionary.

In my opinion the DynamicResource is crashing in this case and don't change. I don't have a proof that it is really crashing. The only fact I have is, that the textbox won't change if an entry does not exist!
Is there a way to handle this crash? (if it is one)

I hope I have all information you need. If not please let me know

Comment: Does it actually "crash" or is the TextBlock just don't change?

Comment: @mm8 Like I said it is only my opinion. I don't know if it crashes. 
The only thing I know is, that it doesn't change. If the entry is available it works fine and changes the textbox. I also edited the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Assuming following situation: I am running the software in spanish and want to change it to german, but one entry in the dictionary is not available, then the software is not using the default entry for it. I still has the value from the spanish dictionary.

This is the expected behaviour. The target property that is set using the `DynamicResource` markup extension will only change when the resource is changed. If the resource is *removed*, the target property won't get reset.

You should make sure that each `ResourceDictionary` contains the exact same translation keys.

The other option would be to implement your own custom markup extension. Please refer to the following links for more information about this.

https://wpftutorial.net/LocalizeMarkupExtension.html
http://10rem.net/blog/2011/03/09/creating-a-custom-markup-extension-in-wpf-and-soon-silverlight
https://github.com/SeriousM/WPFLocalizationExtension
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/35159/wpf-localization-using-resx-files

Comment: Ah ok. I thought (hoped) there was some kind of method already implemented. I will look into this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you change the language, do you change all of these culture settings ?

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = newCultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = newCultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCultureInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming following situation: I am running the software in spanish and want to change it to german, but one entry in the dictionary is not available, then the software is not using the default entry for it. I still has the value from the spanish dictionary.

That makes sense. Why should the value change if there was no entry at all!

I suggest adding the missing entries in each 'language' resource dictionary with an empty string value.